# How to check if the browser can play mp4 via html5 video tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

How to check if the browser can play mp4 via html5 video tag?

Answer (score 55):

This might help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">'.
   var canPlay = false;
   var v = document.createElement('video');
   if(v.canPlayType && v.canPlayType('video/mp4').replace(/no/, '')) {
       canPlay = true;
   }

   alert(canPlay);

</script>
```

Comment: Alex Polo's comment above is exactly what you need. Also, there is a perfectly good reason to check for the browser's ability to play a video format. Firefox does not support MP4. Chrome, Safari, MobileSafari, and IE9 do. Even if you include a Flash player fallback (in the manner you'd show a JPEG fallback to browsers that don't support HTML5 video), Firefox does not resort to it and instead displays a broken video player.

Answer (score 13):

Alex Polo's reply is not bad but incomplete try this to check if the codec is supported too:

```
var mp4Supported = (!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2'));
```

Likewise for ogg, webm and so on ... Works with audio too :)

Answer (score 9):

This following link explains how:

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video-formats

Comment: Which links to [Detecting HTML5 Features](http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html#video), which says, "The `<video>` element is designed to be usable without any detection scripts. You can specify multiple video files, and browsers that support HTML5 video will choose one based on what video formats they support." Hey, that's what I wrote! And just after that, of course, Mark recommends [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). Sound familiar? There are scripts to check what format(s) a given browser supports, but there's rarely a need to actually *do* that.

Comment: yes but if you only have the ability to support 1 video format, detection is needed to handle it. Like i said below CSS and other technologies are supposed to work in a similar manner but we all know you need detection and hacks. to answer the original question with "just works" doesn't solve or truly answer the question. the link I posted does.

Comment: No, that's not the way the `video` tag works. Please, do some reading up on this before saying things with no basis. The **whole point** of the `video` tag is format independence, and the way it does that is through fallbacks.  Only want to support a single video format? Great! Do that, and include a JPG as a fall back. End of story. [Of course, *why* you'd use the `video` tag if you only wanted to support, say, Flash is another question, but that's not what was asked.]

Comment: Thanks, I have done some reading. I know what the whole point of the tag is. I also read the question and answered it. If you think you know best, and exactly what the OP wanted the information for from the one line question, great - you can read minds. Don't presume to know what he/she wants to do with the information.

Comment: @Dori - I was looking for a detection method as well. Not everyone wants to import video into Adobe Premier, process it into a different format, upload it to a server, write out another line of code, and refresh the html file when they have a video of a specific format that they intend to replace with a direct link to the file if it cannot be played. It seems you might not be viewing the entire scope of the original post's purpose ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have to  check if the html5 video is displayed, to hide my personal button to play and turn audio off in ie7 and ie8. My solution is shown below.

My html:

```
<div id="contenitore_video" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
    <video id="cont_video"  autoplay onFocus="this.blur();" width="100%" height="100%"   >
        <source src="video/xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="video/xxx.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <div id="sfondo_ridimensionato" >
            <img src="img/sfondo_home1.jpg"  >      
        </div>
    </video> 
</div>

...

<div id="controlli_video" style="position:absolute; top:10px;right:25px; height:50px; text-align:right;">
    <a class="video_play" onFocus="this.blur();" style="display:none;" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="controlla_video(1)">Play</a> ...

</div
```

My JS ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //controllo se il video funziona o si vede il video alternativo
    //  var numero = $('#sfondo_ridimensionato:hidden').length;
    //  alert(numero);

    if($('#sfondo_ridimensionato:hidden').length == 0){
        $('#controlli_video').hide();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function to validate if your browser is able to play audio or video element

```
    const checkMedia = mediaType => {
    let canPlay = false
    const mediaFormat = {
      audio: 'audio/mp3',
      video: 'video/mp4'
    }
      let media = document.createElement(mediaType)
    if (
      media.canPlayType &&
      media.canPlayType(mediaFormat[mediaType]).replace(/no/, '')
    ) {
      canPlay = true
    }
      return canPlay
    }
```