# How to determine if the guest web browser supports html5 <video>

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am currently deploying a video platform. Videos are currently listed with the JWPlayer's plugin integration. I would like to set by default the `<video>` html5 tag, only if the guest's web browser supports it. How can I do to check if the .flv (encoded video format) is supported by the `<video>` tag of the guest's web browser ?

Should I implement a javascript function ?

Comment: See here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<video>` tags allow content between the tags. [Only when the browser does not support `<video>`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-html-5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash/) will the content within be rendered on the page.

```
<video> 
    <source ogg>
    <source mp4>
    <embed flv /> <!-- embed only rendered if video not supported-->
</video>
```