# Detect Firefox MP4 support (Now Firefox has partial support)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mp4

I'm attempting to display a video in Firefox. The video has to be in MP4, converting the video isn't an option. However this will only work in some situations as Firefox relies on OS level support for MP4, rather than built in support.

It's ok that it won't always work, but I want to be able to detect when it will fail.

I've tried several existing solutions on StackOverflow ( [How to check if the browser can play mp4 via html5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag) )

My current testing code reads:

```
var mp4Supported = (!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2'));
if (!mp4Supported) { console.log("MP4 not supported") } else { console.log("MP4 supported") };
```

However since Firefox now does (technically) support MP4, this seems to always return true, whether the video can be decoded or not.

Console output from the above on Firefox where there's no native support for MP4:

```
"MP4 supported"
Media resource <My resource URL> could not be decoded.
```

Does anyone know of a reliable way to detect successful running now that Firefox has partial support?

Comment: You could try playing a very small MP4 file? I'd also interested to see whether there's a difference between a `"maybe"` vs `"probably"` response on a MP4-supporting OS vs not. Currently you treat all non-empty responses the same.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which platforms are giving you false positives?

Comment: Your code correctly returns `false` for me, on WinXP.