# I'm trying to play video using html 5 but its not working

Tags: html

Here is the code what i'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
<source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
Video courtesy of 
<a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

i'm using Mozilla browser and its version is 4.3

Comment: check if the video tag is supported by the browser.
Try this alert(!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType);

You can also check if it supports the particular video format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag

Comment: yes its supported by the browser

Comment: I'm getting player showing as "No video with supported format and MIME type found"... How can i solve this issue

Comment: check your video, if its of the correct format. Also, check your video path.
It will be helpful, if you can share a working link of the video.