# How does web browser know format and protocol for video tag?

Tags: video, browser, video-streaming, html5-video

In video tag type one specifies a container (like ogg or mp4).

```
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://localhost:666/desktop.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

How does the web browser know stream's codec and protocol it should use to display it?

Comment: This may answer your question from a similar question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag

Comment: Protocol is always http(s) and it downloads the file header to determine the codec.