# Notify user that video file is not supported by browser

Tags: javascript, html, file, video

How can I notify user that file (using as source in HTML video tag) is not supported by browser?
So I am looking for any event or property that can tell me that file is not valid or not supported by video tag.

```
<video src="sample.avi"></video>
```

Scenario:

1. User uploads some file into the system.
2. System shows just uploaded file as a preview.

Goal: Display message that selected video file can't be previewed (is not supported by video tag in this browser).

Thanks

Comment: `<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8/VP9 or MP4 with H.264.
</video>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the browser can play mp4 via html5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572113/how-to-check-if-the-browser-can-play-mp4-via-html5-video-tag)

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/detect-supported-video-formats-javascript

Comment: This is not a case. You are talking about supporting of the video tag, but my question is related to the file that browser can't play.

Comment: @user770 thank you. It seems this is what I am looking for.